# Bad encoding for messages with Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

Tags: node.js, imap, nodemailer

I use

```
   const IMAP = require('imap');
   const simpleParser = require('mailparser').simpleParser;

 f.on('message', (messageSource, seqno) => {

                let message = {
                    seqno: seqno,
                    attributes: null,
                    body: null
                };

                //Fired if options "bodies" is set
                messageSource.on('body', (stream) => {

                    let buffer = '';

                    stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
                        buffer += chunk.toString('utf8');
                    });

                    stream.on('end', () => {
                        message.body = buffer;
                    });

                });

                messageSource.once('attributes', (attributes) => {
                    message.attributes = attributes;
                });

                messageSource.once('end', () => {
                    messages.push(message);
                });

            });
```

Incoming emails that have content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Cyrillic is not displayed well

пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ!

Comment: Please show enough code to reproduce this. As it stands, the question cannot be answered and should be closed.

Comment: Nice edit. A clear improvement. Still not quite there, since you don't have an example of the input that fails... but I have a hunch that your code works for bodyparts that have `content-type: text/…; charset=utf8` or `charset=us-ascii` and `content-transfer-encoding: 7bit`, `8bit` or `binary`, and does not work for bodyparts with other charsets or encodings. Is my guess correct?

Comment: hm, probably Yes

Comment: Have the same problem. And even cant understand what type of coding there is here. This site is have the same coding http://orbitaart.ru/Bolg_Alb_Kaliopa.html